# Probability of missing the true proportion of black vehicles in a population

Tags: probability, statistics

This is for a homework question, but I'm kind of confused on how I can solve it, or what the question is really asking for.

For this question I had to observe 100 vehicles where $Y_i = 1$ if the $i^{th}$ vehicle observed is black, and $Y_i = 0$ otherwise.

So I collected data and found that the mean, $\bar{Y}_{100}$ = 0.21

I also found the standard error $SE$ to be $0.4093602$.

I was then asked to report the 95% confidence interval for the proportion of black vehicles in the population, so I did:

$0.21 \pm 1.960 \times SE = 0.21 \pm 0.802346 \approx (-0.5924, 1.0124)$

Now the question asks "What is the probability of missing the true proportion of black vehicles in the population?"

Since I'm pretty sure my confidence interval covers the estimated proportion and not the true proportion, how could I even get the probability of missing the true proportion?

Comment: Where did you get the $0.802346$ (just the approximate amount, let alone six significant digits)?

Comment: @BrianTung Sorry I accidentally cut off a portion of the ending number for the $SE$. I got $0.802346$ by multiplying $1.960 \times 0.4093602$

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I mean, where did you get the $0.4093602$?  Is that something like $\sqrt{(0.21)(0.79)}$?

Comment: My next comment is that your SE is almost certainly that of a single observation, not the SE of the fraction of $100$ observations that are black vehicles.

Comment: My notes say that $SE = \sqrt{\frac{\bar{Y}_{100} \times (1 - \bar{Y}_{100})}{n}}$ where $n$ is the sample size.

Comment: Shouldn't that therefore give you $\sqrt{\frac{(0.21)(0.79)}{100}} \doteq 0.041$?  (You should only have two significant digits in your SE.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute correct answer is that the probability of missing the true proportion is either 0 (you didn't miss it) or 1 (you did miss it).

This was explicitly mentioned on p.348 of J. Neyman's [paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/91337?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) where he originally introduced to confidence interval.

Think about it this way: the proportion of black cars is the population is a *constant* $b$. This constant is either within or not within the confidence interval you calculated. If it is within then the probability that you missed it is 0; if it is not within then the probability that you missed it is 1.

What a confidence interval says is that if you repeated your experiment many times, then 95% of the confidence interval would contain $b$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Practical_Example_Interpretation

Answer (score 1):

For the actual question, you should interpret the "$95$-percent confidence interval" literally.  See here, under Meaning and Interpretation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval